# How to bind arguments to given values in Python functions?

Tags: python

I have a number of functions with a combination of positional and keyword arguments, and I would like to bind one of their arguments to a given value (which is known only after the function definition). Is there a general way of doing that?

My first attempt was:

```
def f(a,b,c): print a,b,c

def _bind(f, a): return lambda b,c: f(a,b,c)

bound_f = bind(f, 1)
```

However, for this I need to know the exact args passed to `f`, and cannot use a single function to bind all the functions I'm interested in (since they have different argument lists).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def f(a, b, c):
...   print a, b, c
...
>>> bound_f = partial(f, 1)
>>> bound_f(2, 3)
1 2 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `partial` if you wanted to bind the second or third argument?

Comment: You can bind all arguments `bound_f = partial(f, 1, 2, 3)` and then call `bound_f()`

Comment: @MarkRansom You can use named arguments to bind any argument. Example: `partial(f, b=2)`.

Answer (score 21):

You probably want the [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function from functools.

Answer (score 17):

As suggested by MattH's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188134/2289509), `functools.partial` is the way to go.

However, your question can be read as "how can I implement `partial`". What your code is missing is the use of [`*args`, `**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/2289509)- 2 such uses, actually:

```
def partial(f, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped(*args2, **kwargs2):
        return f(*args, *args2, **kwargs, **kwargs2)
    return wrapped
```

Comment: If you're going to use this on **very old python versions** (_in my case Jython 2.1_) and this gives a **`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`** on `*args2` just merge `args`/`args2` and `kwargs`/`kwargs2`. My **solution** was the following (lines after `wrapped(...)`): `new_args = args + args2` followed by `new_kwargs = kwargs.copy()` and `new_kwargs.update(kwargs2)`. Then change the returned function line to `return f(*new_args, **new_kwargs)`. It **will work** with no problems

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [`update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) to bind arguments to given values and *preserve* `__name__` and `__doc__` of the original function:

```
from functools import partial, update_wrapper


def f(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)


bound_f = update_wrapper(partial(f, 1000), f)

# This will print 'f'
print(bound_f.__name__)

# This will print 1000, 4, 5
bound_f(4, 5)
```