# Python alternative to Javascript function.bind()?

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bind

In Javascript, one might write

```
var ids = ['item0', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3']; // variable length
function click_callback(number, event)
{
    console.log('this is: ', number);
}
for (var k = 0; k < ids.length; k += 1)
{
    document.getElementById(ids[k]).onclick = click_callback.bind(null, k);
}
```

So I can pass to the callback function the value of `k` at the time it is registered even though it has changed by the time the function is called.

Does Python have a way to do something equivalent?

---

The specific situation is this (but I prefer a general answer):

I have a variable number of matplotlib plots (one for each coordinate). Each has a SpanSelector, which was for some reason designed to only pass the two limit points to the callback function. However, they all have the same callback function. So I have:

```
def span_selected(min, max):
```

but I need

```
def span_selected(which_coordinate, min, max):
```

At the time of registering the callback, I of course know the coordinate, but I need to know it when the function is called. In Javascript, I would do something like

```
callback = span_selected.bind(null, coordinate)
```

What would I do in Python?

Comment: I found the answer here on SO shortly after posting this (writing it down helps construct better search queries apparently). Should I delete the question as a duplicate, or answer it so other people who use javascript related search words might find the solution more easily?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "one for each coordinate".  If you have multiple plots, I think you should have a separate SpanSelector for each plot.

Comment: What is the duplicate question?  Often better to mark it as duplicate so it's still findable as a signpost to the answer.

Comment: Okay I'll do that, and I'll edit to clarify the part about SpanSelectors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turned out it was already answered here: [How to bind arguments to given values in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188048/how-to-bind-arguments-to-given-values-in-python-functions)

The solution is:

```
from functools import partial
def f(a,b,c):
    print a,b,c
bound_f = partial(f,1)
bound_f(2,3)
```

Full credits to [MattH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267781/matth).

EDIT: so in the example, instead of

```
callback = span_selected.bind(null, coordinate)
```

use

```
callback = partial(span_selected, coordinate)
```