# Default argument to Python attribute that is a function

Tags: python

I was wondering if it is possible in Python to specify a default argument to a function attribute in Python (I know this is not the right terminology so here is an example):

```
def foo(x, y): 
    return x + y

my_foo = foo(y=50)

my_foo(25) #returns 75
```

Does this sound possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188048/how-to-bind-arguments-to-given-values-in-python-functions.

Comment: To have a default argument, use def foo(x=0, y=0): [...] directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import partial
def foo(x, y): return x + y
my_foo = partial(foo, y=50)
my_foo(100)
Out[433]: 150
```

But you should know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811247/how-to-fill-specific-positional-arguments-with-partial-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

You'd do it in the function definition:

```
def foo(x, y=50):
    return x+y
```

if y isn't specified 50 is the default value:

```
print foo(25) # 25 is the value for x, y gets the default 50
```

Comment: Your answer is only valid only because it doesn't matter which argument gets the default value for this particular sample function -- a fairly unique situation -- so isn't something generally applicable.